# Get data from SQL as XML

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I would really appreciate  some assistance. I'm using the SQL FOR XML PATH but I have some issues with the nodes.

I have a simple table (below is the script for generating)

```
voucher_number  payment_number  payment_date
---------------------------------------------------
D15             C15             2020-07-27
D16             C16             2020-07-25
```

I would like the XML to look like this, look at the level of "object":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<objects>
   <object>
      <record>
         <voucher_number>D15</voucher_number>
         <payment_number>C15</payment_number>
         <payment_date>2020-07-27</payment_date>
      </record>
      <record>
         <voucher_number>D16</voucher_number>
         <payment_number>C16</payment_number>
         <payment_date>2020-07-25</payment_date>
      </record>
   </object>
</objects>
```

But when I run this script

```
SELECT 
      [voucher_number] as   [record/voucher_number]
      ,[payment_number] as  [record/payment_number]
      ,[payment_date] as    [record/payment_date]
  FROM #t1
FOR XML PATH ('object'), ROOT('Objects')
```

it looks like this.... look at the level of "object".

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <Objects>
      <object>
          <record>
             <voucher_number>D15</voucher_number>
             <payment_number>C15</payment_number>
             <payment_date>2020-07-27</payment_date>
          </record>
       </object>
      <object>
          <record>
             <voucher_number>D16</voucher_number>
             <payment_number>C16</payment_number>
             <payment_date>2020-07-25</payment_date>
          </record>
       </object>
    </Objects>
```

How should I change the script to make the  to spann the two "record" child nodes?

Many, many thanks in advance :)

```
--- Script to generate the test table ---
Create table #t1 
    (
    [voucher_number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [payment_number] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [payment_date] [date] NULL
    )

INSERT #t1 ([voucher_number], [payment_number], [payment_date]) VALUES (N'D15', N'C15',  CAST(N'2020-07-27' AS Date))
GO
INSERT #t1 ([voucher_number], [payment_number], [payment_date]) VALUES (N'D16', N'C16', CAST(N'2020-07-25' AS Date))
```

Comment: XML support is **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method, using some nested `FOR XML` queries:

```sql
SELECT (SELECT V.voucher,
               V.payment,
               V.date
        FROM (VALUES('D15','C15',CONVERT(date,'20200727')),
                    ('D16','C16',CONVERT(date,'20200725')))V(voucher, payment, date)
        FOR XML PATH('record'), ROOT('object'),TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('objects');
```